# What policy templates should an AWS IAM user have in order to deploy an EB application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, account, amazon-iam

What policy templates should an AWS IAM user have in order to deploy and maintain an EB application (e.g. website code from a client machine)? IAMReadOnlyAccess plus PowerUserAccess seem sufficient, but I'm wondering whether the latter is overkill. Can I restrict policies to a single EB instance or application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an IAM role in the Web Console, there is a pre-defined role called `ElasticBeanstalkFullAccess`. This will give you full permission to all underlying resources that elastic beanstalk needs. You can see the [general doc on this.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.templates.html)

Restricting to specific environments or applications is much harder, but doable. It requires you to restrict the user to specific resources using arn's, including all underlying resources and their arn's. [See the doc on this.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.policies.html)

For reference, the full elastic beanstalk policy looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:*",
        "ec2:*",
        "elasticloadbalancing:*",
        "autoscaling:*",
        "cloudwatch:*",
        "s3:*",
        "sns:*",
        "cloudformation:*",
        "rds:*",
        "sqs:*",
        "iam:PassRole"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```